# Simplifying cypher, match all nodes and relationships between two node types

Tags: neo4j, cypher, agens-graph

Is there anyway to further simplify this query?
I want to go from `kingdom` to all the `species`, there are nodes related towards the species nodes. The image shows the result of this query, but is there any way to match the `kingdom` node and all the nodes and relationships until the species node. If you like: all nodes/relationships between kingdom and species.

There will never be a node not attached to the kingdom or species objects (it's a taxonomic hierarchy).
The `RELTYPE` will probably change to something more meaningful.

```
MATCH (k:Kingdom)-
[:RELTYPE]->(p:Phylum)-
[:RELTYPE]-(c:Class)-
[:RELTYPE]-(o:Order)-
[:RELTYPE]-(f:Family)-
[:RELTYPE]-(g:Genus)-
[:RELTYPE]-(s:Species)
RETURN k, p, c, o, f, g, s
```

[image]

Comment: match path=(:Kingdom)-->(:Species) return nodes(path) as node

Comment: @GovindSingh, you should put a relationship type or it is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to specify the relationship types, but it is good practice to set an upper limit (even if it's a high one). For example:

```
MATCH p=(:Kingdom)-[*..15]->(:Species)
RETURN nodes(p)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a variable length relationship in your query. *6 means you can get the nodes from Kingdom up to max of six hops (or relationships) until you reach Species. Then from this path, return all nodes that you found.

```
MATCH p=(:Kingdom)-[:RELTYPE*6]-(:Species)
RETURN nodes(p)
```

Comment: This works, you were correct about needing to specify the relationship. But in the future the `RELTYPE` will change to something meaningful and wont be the same at all levels. I'd also rather avoid having to know how many levels exist before hand.

Comment: yes, you're right @SpatialDigger. If the relationship type (or name) is different then it will not work.  if you want to avoid getting the number of levels exist before hand, then you can put a big number and you will get the same result, For example, put :RELTYPE*99 is the same with :RELTYPE*6 since 99 is a max number not meant to be exact.

Comment: @SpatialDigger, please approve my answer as well to get that +15points :D. Thanks.

Comment: I've given you an up vote, I'll leave it open for a while in case someone has a full solution.

Comment: we (or community) will answer based on the question, if you want more answers on your more questions, then it should be another SO question. This community is based on trust rather than satisfaction.

Comment: It is the same question, if I post it again the community will rightly block it. I value your input greatly, but it is up to me when/if I accept an answer. I clarified the question, you will get your 'points' if a full 100% answer does not appear over the next few days, afterall you built on @GovindSingh's answer, which is how the community works. Patience is a virtue. If you disagree with my reasoning you can report this post to the community and they can decide.

Comment: If the types in the path or the depth can change later, then you can either include all the possible rel types separated by `|`, or you can omit the type and it will match on all of them. The limit of `6` can also be dropped, so it would just be `p=(:Kingdom)-[*]->(:Species)`. Keeping a direction in the pattern may help, in case the graph ever changes such that it's no longer a tree. In any case, using a variable-length pattern like this is the right choice.